# SyntaxError: invalid flag after regular expression and white screen

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, syntax-error

I can't figure out why my page will not work. It just gives me a white screen when I try to load it. Is there a code I am missing? I don't know if my spaces matter either. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><body>
<title>Initializing an Array</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {width:10em}
th {text-align:left}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- 
{//create (declare) two new arrays
var n1=new Array(5); //allocate five-element Array
var n2=new Array (); //allocate empty Array

//assign values to each element of Array n1
for ( var i = 0; i <n1.length; ++i )
n1[ i ] = i;

//create and initialize five elements in Array n2
for ( i=0; i <5; ++i )
n2[ i ] = i;

outputArray("Array n1:",n1);
outputArray("Array n2:",n2);

//output the heading followed by a two-column table
//containing subscripts and elements of "theArray"
function outputArray (heading,theArray)}
{
document.writeln("<h2>"+heading+"</h2>");
document.writeln("table border=\"1\"");
document.writeln("<thead><th>Subscripts</th>"+"<th>Value</th></thead>    <tbody>");

//output the subscript and value of each array element
for ( var i = 0; i <theArray.length; i++ )
document.writeln("<tr><td>+i+"</td><td>"+theArray[i]+"</td></tr>");

document.writeln("/tbody></table>");
} //end function outputArray
//-->

</script>

</head></body>
</html>
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: `document.writeln("<tr><td>+i+"</td><td>"+theArray[i]+"</td></tr>");` This line is even highlighted like RegEx in the question. You forgot a `"`. This is a typo.

Comment: Also, those `document.writeln` lines ___will___ result in invalid HTML because HTML tags are automatically ___closed___ once they are written to the page.

Comment: `<head><body>---</head></body>` ??? No wonder nothing gets displayed. Should be `<head>------</head><body>-----<body>`.

Comment: So what should I use instead?

Comment: @BriaNicole For a start, don’t use `document.write` or `document.writeln`. Those two don’t support dynamically writing complex markup to the page. Use functions and attributes like `appendChild`, `innerHTML`, `getElementById`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken HTML and invalid Javascript.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
```

For your `DOCTYPE` of html, there is no need to specify any attributes to a `<script>` tag except `src`, and that is only needed if you are loading an external script file.  And there is no attribute `language`.  You likely meant `type="text/javascript"` but that is the default and therefore redundant.

```
<!--
```

You can't have HTML comments inside a `<script>` block.  You are telling the browser that what is inside the `<script>` block is Javascript, then you putting invalid javascript.  There will likely be errors displayed in the console.

Your example, tidied up, would look something like this:

```
<script>

    // create (declare) two new arrays
    var n1 = new Array(5); //allocate five-element Array
    var n2 = new Array(); //allocate empty Array

    // assign values to each element of Array n1
    for (var i = 0; i < n1.length; ++i) {
        n1[ i ] = i;
    }

    // create and initialize five elements in Array n2
    for (i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
        n2[ i ] = i;
    }

    outputArray("Array n1:",n1);
    outputArray("Array n2:",n2);

    // output the heading followed by a two-column table
    // containing subscripts and elements of "theArray"
    function outputArray (heading, theArray) {
        var html = '<h2>' + heading + '</h2>';

        html += '<table border="1">';
        html += '<thead><th>Subscripts</th><th>Value</th></thead>';
        html += '<tbody>';

        // output the subscript and value of each array element
        for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + theArray[i] + '</td></tr>';
        }

        html += '</tbody></table>';

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = html;

        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @Xufox bah!  Was bound to happen... source was a *mess*.  Why on EARTH do people not have pride in their code?  It's like writing a novel without understanding grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quote `"` and on the next line `<` in `</tbody>` in last `for` loop.

```
document.writeln("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+theArray[i]+"</td></tr>");
                          ^
document.writeln("</tbody></table>");  
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course nothing gets displayed, the base HTML layout is completely wrong.

You wrote :

```
<head>
  <body>
     (all the stuff)
  </head>
</body>
```

It should be :

```
<head>
   (scripts.....)
</head>
<body>
   (HTML....)
</body>
```